# Making while-loop in php (variable is defined, but it is acting like undefined)

Tags: php, while-loop

I am learning PHP form book and I have found one thing in this part of the code

**EDIT:**

```
$count_per_column  =  ceil($num_powers/$num_columns);
$num_columns       =  min($max_columns, ceil($num_powers/$threshold));
echo '<table><tr><td>';
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    if(($i > 0) && ($i % $count_per_column == 0)) {
        echo '</td><td>';   
    }

    echo '<input type="checkbox" name="powers[]" value= "' . $row['power_id'] . '" />';
    echo $row['power'] . '<br/>';
    $i++;    
} 

echo '</td></tr></table>';
```

Is it correct? Isnt there a problem with `$i++` ? because the code should make multiple columns with 5 lines. And it making only columns with power and error

> **Division by zero in / Notice:** Undefined variable: count_per_column

In the line where is the `If`is. When I put away `$i++` It isn't showing errors. But making only one column.

Comment: You haven't defined `$count_per_column` anywhere

Comment: `$count_per_column = ceil($num_powers/$num_columns);`

Comment: have you made sure that you are retrieving anything at all in your $result?

Comment: `$num_columns` can't be 0. You can never divide something by 0. Put a check (`if`-statement) to make sure that your variables are set, and that `$num_columns` is not zero.

Comment: if I add first thing to power so in result is one power it will correctly show added power. But errors show with 2., 3. ...adding, with name of power.

Comment: You define $count_per_column before you define $num_columns. That seems wrong?